# How can I prevent node program from stop running?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see many applications that uses node runs forever.

Therefore, I tried using `setInterval` method, which I assumed it will let it run forever, but apparently it doesn't.

```
var request = require('request');

var queue = function(item) {
  request({
    uri: 'http://www.google.net'
  },
  function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
  })
};
setInterval(queue("google"),1000); //do this every 1 second.
```

When I run above program, it stops after a second.

How can I can modify above codes to keep it running if I run it with node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have a bug in your code:

`setInterval(queue("google"),1000); //do this every 1 second.`

Instead of passing a function above as the first parameter, you are passing the result of executing a function.

So either do `setInterval(queue, 1000)` or do the following if you want multiple params:

```
setInterval(function() {
  queue(how_many_params_you_want);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

a much better solution is using the npm: [forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever)

Comment: I have been using forever, but there seems to be bug in recent versions... `forever list` does not show the list of running processes started by `forever start`

Comment: I've only used it when I was hosting on my server. Haven't tried it since shifting to Heroku

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign setInterval to a local variable.

```
setInterval(function(){},1000);
```

will stop.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){},1000);
```

will not.